# variables wordpress

Tags: wordpress, variables-globales

Tengo un problema con una variable que debo utilizar.
Tengo que pasar una variable (es un array) de un plugin, que yo he creado, a el functions.php del tema de wordpress que estoy utilizando. ¿Cómo lo debo hacer?
Mi plugin está dentro de su carpeta correspondiente y dentro de la carpeta plugins.

Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda

Buenos días
Si, he probado con el include pero da error y no funciona.
Para aclarar un poco más la situación:
Yo tengo una función en una carpeta dentro de la carpeta de los plugins  que básicamente recoge las respuestas de un formulario en una array. Ese array es el que necesito en el functions.php
Y el array se guarda en los plugins porque es un plugin que yo he hecho. Este plugin funciona bien.
El problema es sacar el valor de esa variable y usarlo en el functions.

```html
 $formato = menu_cookies();
```

$formato es el array que yo guardo en mi plugin y que quiero usar dentro de functions.php, como argumento de otra función.

```html
function crea_aviso($formato){
    echo 'estamos en la functions.php y me he traido el array guardado en mi plugin';
   }
```

Espero que ahora esté un poco más claro.
Por favor, una ayudita
MUUUUUUChas gracias

Comment: Has probado a hacer un include del archivo donde se encuentra la variable al functions.php? es la forma mas rápida que se me ocurre, sin ver código ni nada.

Comment: Buenos días. Intenta usar los comentarios para responder y la pregunta solo para añadir información relacionada con la misma. Así será mas cómodo para todos. Si pones @seguidodelnombredelusuario se le notifica cuando respondas a su pregunta y así nos damos por enterados los interesados. No puedes montar la function crea_aviso dentro del plugin? o guardar los datos en la base de datos?.

Comment: Guardarlo en la base de datos es una solución pero no la que me gustaría usar. También había pensado guardarlo en un simple archivo de texto pero no me deja escribir en él, sólo puedo leer. Y sí, ya tenía la función crea_aviso en el plugin y todo funcionaba, pero con esa función yo creo un shortcode y eso sólo me deja hacerlo dentro del functions. Tal vez también pueda crear el shortcode en el plugin y luego usarlo pero hasta ahora eso no ha funcionado. Gracias

Comment: Lo digo, no porque no puedas hacerlo, como te ha indicado, muy acertadamente, @DavidNavarro mas abajo, si no porque lo correcto es que un plugin gestione todo lo que pertenece a ese plugin. Si necesitas modificar manualmente un archivo como el functions.php algo hay mal o que no estás teniendo en cuenta. Por otro lado, cuidado con las variables globales.

Answer (score 0):

declara ua variable global en los dos lados donde la usas

```
global $form;
// Insertas contenido
$form = array [.....];
```

Luego en functions.php haces lo mismo y los datos estaran disponibles

```
global $form;
// Haces lo que quieras con los datos
echo $form['text'];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eso ya lo he probado y no funciona, me dice: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1"

Comment: El uso de globales es considerado por lo general una mala práctica. @Gema, ¿por qué no pasas `$formato` en parámetro a la función? Creo que deberías explicar cómo se relaciona el código para poder ayudarte, pues no dices nada al respecto. O sea, ¿cómo llamas al código de `functions.php` desde el plugin?